# Query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to select a field in table 'reasons' but I have to get the field 'reason' in the table 'customer_complaint' these tables are related.

This is my model:

```
function reason(){  
   $reason = $this->db->select("*")->from('reason')->join('customer_complaint','customer_complaint.reason=reasons.reason_id')->get();
    return $reason->results();
}
```

and I'm getting this error on the screen:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1146
>
> Table 'complaint.reason' doesn't exist

```
"SELECT * FROM `reason` JOIN `customer_complaint` ON `customer_complaint`.`reason`=`reasons`.`reason_id`"
```

The query works fine in MySQL workbench but I think I'm getting this error because the framework are omitting 'customer_'.

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors I can see

First Table `reason` you mentioned used in Two form, 1. `reason`, 2. `reasons`

Make spelling correct first.

Second you use `results()` method which is wrong, it should `result()`

So If your table name is `reasons` then your query should be as following

```
 public function reason(){  
   $reason = $this->db->select('*')->from('reasons')->join('customer_complaint','customer_complaint.reason = reasons.reason_id')->get();
    return $reason->result();
}
```

and now try

Answer (score 0):

You must use return $reason->result. The database name is complaint? The table ne